# Finding the jordan form of a funny looking matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was working on this problem from a previous qual exam. Just when I thought I knew how to find the Jordan form of any matrix and  then I find this....aaaargh :)

> Find the jordan form of the following matrix: $$ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 &  &  \\2 & 1 &  \\ & 2 & 1\end{array}\right)$$

**Thoughts**: I thought about inserting variable names to the empty spaces
but then got a messy determinant to compute. I'm thinking that this is
somehow one of those trick questions. May be there's something here that
I'm not seeing. I can see a bit of a resemblance to a Jordan block here in 
that we have $1$'s on the diagonal and $2$'s on the sub-diagonal. But what
am I to make of the empty spaces? Am I supposed to take them as zero? Or just
any old numbers?

Can anybody help?

Comment: I think it would be a good guess that the empty spaces are zeros.  On a qual, if you make such a (reasonable) assumption then proceed to answer the question correctly with that assumption, you're usually going to bode well.  You might mention that the question was unclear however!

Comment: The empty spaces are almost always meant to be zeros when dealing with matrices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the usual convention that empty space $\,=0\;$ , we get:

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-1&0&0\\-2&x-1&0\\0&-2&x\end{vmatrix}=x(x-1)^2$$

Calculating quickly we can see the eigenspace of $\,\lambda=1\,$ has dimension $\,1\,$ , from where we get the JCF for the matrix

$$J_A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\
0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

one block of size one for $\,\lambda =0\;$ , and one block of size two for $\,\lambda =1\,$ .

Comment: The above answer refers to the originally posted matrix, with a  lower right entry equal to zero.

Comment: So the convention is empty spaces= zero?. Wow, I never knew that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I made a mistake in one of the entries. But it was the empty spaces that was throwing me off.

Comment: The above convention is just a matter of comfort, @user54755: it saves writing/typing, and I think it is completely safe to assume this convention **unless** otherwise explicitly stated.

Comment: @DonAntonio  I think $$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-1&0&0\\-2&x-1&0\\0&-2&x\end{vmatrix}=x(x-1)^2$$ should be replaced by $$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-1&0&0\\-2&x-1&0\\0&-2&x-1\end{vmatrix}=(x-1)^3$$. And also Since the given matrix is triangular then it's immediate that $1$ is its only eigenvalue as user63181 commented. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: The original matrix had a zero in the last entry, @learner> check it.

Comment: @DonAntonio   Ahhh..I got it ..Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Since the given matrix is triangular then it's immediate that $1$ is its only eigenvalue, moreover we have $\dim\ker(A-I)=1$ and $\dim\ker(A-I)^2=2$ so
$$J_A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

The empty entries are presumably meant to have the value 0 as you suggest. This is a common but not universal convention or rather a convenient writing habit.